# Date in Mongoid queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model:

```
class SimpleAction
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :set_date, :type => Date
```

and I have some data in collection:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f6dd2e83a698b2518000006"), "name" : "lost",
>   "notes" : "", "set_date(1i)" : "2012", "set_date(2i)" : "3",
>   "set_date(3i)" : "25", "set_date(4i)" : "13", "set_date(5i)" : "57",
>   "duration" : 15, "todo" : "4" }

You can see that mongoid store date in the five fields - set_date(ni).

I have two question:

- How can I filter data by set_date field in the mongo console client?  Something like this:

  ```
  db.simple_actions.find({ set_date : { "$lte" : new Date() } })
  ```

  My query didn't return any data.
- How can I filter data by set_date field in my Rails controller? Something like this:

  ```
  @simple_actions = SimpleAction.where(:set_date => { '$lte' => Date.today })
  ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend not using `Date`, but instead `DateTime`:

```
field :set_date, :type => DateTime
```

Now not only will it be stored in 1 field, like so:

```
"set_date" : ISODate("2012-03-14T17:42:27Z")
```

But Mongoid will correctly handle various conversions for queries like you want:

```
SimpleAction.where( :set_date => { :$lte => Date.today } )
```

Comment: Hmm.. I changed model difinition and insert new recodrs in the collection, but nothing changed.

Comment: Here is form fragment:   <%= f.datetime_select :set_date %>

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'nothing changed'? Clearly DateTime is a different field type than date, yes? :)

Comment: For pure experiment I have created new model, controller and view by 'rails g scaffold Testing set_date:datetime'.  Then I created records and look at them on mongodb - set_date field consists of 5 parts.  I have changed Time type to DateTime, created another 2 new records and look at them on mongodb - new records have five-segments on set_date field (set_date(ni)).

Comment: But the set_date field set correctly if I set the line '@testing.set_date = Time.now' into controller. As I see, the problem is into view and datetime_select helper

Comment: What version of Mongoid/MongoDB are you using? I have a large Mongoid+Rails3 project that doesn't show this behavior, and I made a quick test project just now that also doesn't...

Comment: Rails - 3.2.1, Mongoid - 2.4.6.  It is the datetime_select helper problem. I have changed it to text_field and all works fine.

Comment: Odd, well, `datetime_select` is kind of weak anyway right? Probably want to replace it at some point with a fancy little widget of some kind... sounds like you should just do that part now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with class Time.

Rails is so good with Api for mobile (such as Android),when you sent date from mobile to Api like: 1482723520. (last_created=1482723520)

You can use it like that:

```
 time = Time.at(params[:last_created].to_i)
```

And in Rails you can query like that:

```
Number.where(created_at:  { :$gte => time })
```